# Changing default focused screen on awesome wm

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I have a bit of a hacky setup on my laptop where I use [`optimus-manager`](https://github.com/Askannz/optimus-manager) to configure my screen layout at X startup based on whether an external monitor is connected or not. If it is, I only want to use the external monitor and not the laptop monitor, but because of a limitation of NVIDIA drivers, *I need to leave my laptop monitor on, and just lower the backlight brightness*. See my `/etc/optimus-manager/xsetup-hybrid.sh` for how this works (`eDP-1` is my laptop screen, and `HDMI-1-0` is my external monitor):

```
#!/bin/sh

# Everything you write here will be executed by the display manager when setting up the login screen in "hybrid" mode.

xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3000x0 --output HDMI-1-0 --primary --mode 2560x1080 --pos 0x0
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "Not connected to display, don't dim internal monitor"
    exit 0
fi

echo 0 | tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Notice that `eDP-1` (laptop monitor) is positioned at `3000x0`. I've done this to keep the screens far enough apart so that my mouse can't accidentally stray from my external monitor's screen into my laptop monitor's screen.

This works pretty well, but for some reason every time I log into awesome (or anytime I change the screen layout with `xrandr` for that matter), awesome focuses the laptop monitor screen by default, even though `xrandr` is specifying the external monitor screen as `--primary`.

How can I change this behaviour so that my external monitor screen is focused by default if that monitor is connected, falling back to my laptop screen if it isn't?

Comment: What exactly does "awesome focuses the laptop monitor" mean? Are there X11 programs already running when awesome starts and it gives the input focus to one of them on the wrong screen? Or there are no clients and the mouse cursor is warped to "that other" screen?

Comment: What I mean by that is, if I were to open a client (with keybindings), the run prompt, etc., they would open on the laptop monitor (the wrong one, which is *not* the primary `xrandr` screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could warp the mouse cursor to the primary screen in your config:

```lua
mouse.screen = screen.primary
```

The above can also be tested in an already running awesome session via `awesome-client`: `awesome-client 'mouse.screen = screen.primary'`.

If you want to decide the pointer coordinates more precisely (the above uses the upper left corner of the screen), there is `mouse.coords({ x = 42, y = 21 })`.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely apps are being displayed where the mouse currently resides.  You could use **xdotool** to ensure mouse is on desired display to begin with.

```
#!/bin/sh

##  executed by display manager during login

if [ "$?" -eq "0" ] ; then
    xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3000x0 --output HDMI-1-0 --primary --mode 2560x1080 --pos 0x0
    echo 0 | tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

    ##  sudo apt install xdotool
    ##  x, y  coordinates:  half of 2560x1080, so middle of main screen
    xdotool mousemove 1280 540
else
    ##  external display not plugged in
    xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --primary --pos 0x0
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the shout about `xdotool`. The script doesn't quite work, as it runs before the login screen is displayed, but the problem with the mouse moving happens after I log in. I could maybe add it to some sort of login script.

Comment: If I change `echo 0` in my script to, say `echo 10`, I can see the other screen, and can see that there are no apps there. Also, this problem arises anytime I make a change with `[a|x]randr` - as soon as I execute the changes, awesome focuses on the other screen, and the mouse moves to it.

Comment: It's possible you could alias xrandr to append `--output HDMI-1-0 --primary` to any further use of the command, to ensure that's not undone `( .bashrc | .bash_aliases )`.  Otherwise, use a GUI that respects your initial choice, believe ARandR does.

Comment: If I run `xrandr -q`, I can see that `HDMI-1-0` is still the primary output, so I don't think it's getting overridden. In any case, @Uli's answer is more what I was looking for; I'd trust the awesome API to be a little more error-resistant than login scripts